# Accent in UISearchbar

Tags: iphone, ios, encoding, uisearchbar

I'm actually using a UISearchbar for make some queries on a SQLite database. The main problem is when I put an accent like 'é' with the keyboard, this accent is totally wrong. With breakpoints I have '.' instead of 'é' and on the log console I have '√©'.

Is there a way to use accent instead of using some tricks like remove the accent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable that hold your string is probably correct. NSLog doesn't know the encoding used for the string and use the default one. Which one did you use - UTF8? If yes: NSLog(@"%@", [yourString UTF8String]); should display the string you are expected.

Comment: Using this cause me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS :`NSLog(@"%@", [searchText UTF8String]);`

Comment: Is there a way you can find out the encoding? - it might not be UTF8 then

Comment: I found where was my problem thanks your clue about UTF8 encoding, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found my problem.

The string is correctly encoded in UTF8, but when I did some SQLite queries I did them using ASCII encoding, now I use UTF8Encoding

```
const char *query = [stringQuery cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Instead of

```
const char *query = [stringQuery cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```